# How to identify the values of a resistor with printed markings?

Tags: power-supply, resistors

I'm trying to fix my Silverstone SST-ST60F-P 600w power supply which has a burnt resistor. It just so happens I have another psu of the same model so I opened it up to look for the value of the burnt resistor since I can't read the values anymore. The problem is it's not like the usual resistor which is color coded. It has numbers printed on it.

[image: Picture of the resistor]

The values listed on the resistor are R207 337Y. It does have a silver band which should mean it's tolerance is 10% but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is not a resistor. The silver band shows the polarity, I think it's a diode. Maybe a variant (?) of a rectifier: http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/33775/WINGS/RL207/124/1/RL207.html

Comment: I think it might be an FR207 diode. It's hard to see that far around.

Comment: if your dioide blew, there's probably another issue deeper down that caused the failure...

Answer (score 2):

That's a diode. R207 is the part number. The band marks the cathode.